# Syntax understanding in task with matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

can comeone help to understand in MAtlab this:

```
k=2
n = (0:-1:-4)+k
```

the result; 2 1 0 -1 -2

how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with a [colon operator](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) and a vectorized sum at the same time. Let's split the problem into smaller, stand-alone problems:

1. In Matlab, if you add or subtract between a scalar value to a matrix, the arithmetic operation is performed on all the elements of the matrix, in a `vectorized` way. Example:

   `A = [1 2; 3 4]; % 2-by-2 matrix`

   `S1 = A + 2 % output: S1 = [3 4; 5 6]`

   `B = [1 2 3 4] % 1-by-5 matrix, also called column vector`

   `S2 = B - 5 % output: S2 = [3 4 5 6]`
2. The `column operator` in Matlab can be used in many situation: indexing, for iterations and vector creation. In your case, its purpose is the third one and it's syntax is `START(:STEP):END`. The default `STEP`, if not specified, is `1`. The `START` and `END` parameters are never exceeded. Example:

   `A = 1:5 % output: A = [1 2 3 4 5]`

   `B = -2.5:2.5:6 % output: B = [-2.5 0 2.5 5]`

   `C = 1:-1:-5 % output: C = [1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5]`

   `D = -4:-2:0 % output: D = []`
3. In all the programming languages, an operator precedence criterion is defined so that a one-liner calculation that uses multiple operators is atomized into smaller calculations that respect the given priority, unless parentheses are used to redefine the default criterion... just like in common maths. Example

   `A = 2 * 5 + 3 % output: A = 13`

   `B = 2 * (5 + 3) % output: B = 16`

Let's put all this together to provide you an explaination:

```
n = (0:-1:-4) + k
% vector creation has parentheses, so it's executed first
% then, the addition is executed on the result of the first operation
```

Let's subdivide the calculation into intermediate steps:

```
n_1 = 0:-1:-4 % output: n_1 = [0 -1 -2 -3 -4]
n_2 = n_1 + k % output: n_2 = [2  1  0 -1 -2]
n = n_2
```

Want to see what happens without parentheses?

```
n = 0:-1:-4+k % output: n = [0 -1 -2]
```

Why? Because the addition has priority over the colon operator. It's like writing `n = 0:-1:(-4+k)` and adding `k` to the `END` parameter of the colon operator. Let's subdivide the calculation into intermediate steps:

```
n_1 = -4 + k % output: n_1 = -2
n_2 = 0:-1:n_1 % output: n_2 = [0 -1 -2]
n = n_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic Matlab syntax, you're dealing with range operators. There are two patterns:

```
[start]:[end]
```

and

```
[start]:[step]:[end]
```

Patterns like this result in arrays / vectors / "1D matrices".

In your example, you will get a vector first, stepping through the numbers 0 to -4 (step == -1). Then, you are adding k == 2 to all numbers in this vector.

```
octave:1> k = 2
k =  2
octave:2> n = (0:-1:-4)+k
n =

   2   1   0  -1  -2

octave:3> 0:-1:-4
ans =

   0  -1  -2  -3  -4
```

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesizes expression determines an array. The the first number there is the first element, the second is the step and the last one is the last element. So the parenthesizes returns `0 -1 -2 -3 -4`. Next we add `k=2` to each element that results in `2 1 0 -1 -2`